# How to access Rpi via ssh to WSL2 in window 10

Tags: wsl-2

I tried to access WSL2 from raspberry pi by ssh

I watch this video clip however I can not

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yCK3easuYm4&t=727s

First in Rpi to wsl2

ssh user@192.168.0.1 -p 3000

and wsl2 to Rpi

in PowerShell

netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenaddress=0.0.0.0 listenport=3000 connectaddress=192.168.240.40(wsl2) connectport=3000

and I fix the /etc/ssh/sshd_config

Port 3000
ListenAddress 0.0.0.0

However, I got an error in Rpi

--> ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer

Do I have something wrong!

Answer (score 0):

Add a rule to allow the port in Windows Firewall

- inbound rule > +new rule > port > {tcp or udp, 3000}